# How to take snap shot of div or canvas having .svg image loaded?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to take snap shot of a div or canvas having .svg image loaded.
For instance i have tried html2canvas for that's not includes svg image. just took snapshot of other page data.

Comment: Please provide your code. It  would be better if it is jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can** ([as shown in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Y3K57/) - bottom copy is the extracted canvas containing the svg) but there is one exception:

You cannot extract the image if the SVG has any **external references**. If the SVG uses images they need to be inline using either a `Blob` or `data-uri`. Otherwise security will strike.

Other things to note (from [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#Restrictions)) which will affect how the SVG is rendered (when used with a canvas context):

> **Restrictions**
>
> For security purposes, Gecko places some restrictions on SVG content
>   when it's being used as an image:
>
> - JavaScript is disabled.
> - External resources (e.g. images, stylesheets) cannot be loaded, though they can be used if inlined through BlobBuilder object URLs or
>     data: URIs.
> - :visited-link styles aren't rendered.
> - Platform-native widget styling (based on OS theme) is disabled.
>
> Note that the above restrictions are specific to image contexts; they
>   don't apply when SVG content is viewed directly, or when it's embedded
>   as a document via the <iframe>, <object>, or <embed> elements.

Although this mention Gecko it also applies to other browsers.

Besides from that you can use SVG on the canvas and extract it as an image. The only way around this (in regards to grabbing a snaphot and unless you want to parse the SVG manually to inline external content) is to redirect the image links to your server and load page and images from there - which means you somehow need to pre-process (convert) the SVG files.

Comment: @markE oops, my bad. The example I link too was made for something entirely different, I just wanted to show it's possible to grab a canvas with a svg drawn to it (not so much for the foreignObject). This example is probably better suited: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Y3K57/